# Changing the format of rails ActiveRecord Query Tracing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails project with Postgres, I see this in my Rails logs when a query is fired.

```
 MessageThreadsUser Count (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "message_threads_users" WHERE "message_threads_users"."received_unread_at" IS NOT NULL AND "message_threads_users"."user_id" = $1 /*controller='users',action='check_unread'*/  [["user_id", 111]]
```

I want it to show me this instead:

```
 MessageThreadsUser Count (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "message_threads_users" WHERE "message_threads_users"."received_unread_at" IS NOT NULL AND "message_threads_users"."user_id" = 111 /*controller='users',action='check_unread'*/
```

How can I achieve this?